# Matrix scale video on TextureView Android

Tags: android, video, scale, exoplayer

I'm trying to play video with `ExoPlaye` on `TextureView`. In order to scale and crop video to fit view I use matrix. My custom view extends `TextureView' Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {
    updateTextureViewSize(width, height);
    Log.v("EXO", "onVideoSizeChanged() " +  width + "x" + height);
}

private void updateTextureViewSize(float videoWidth, float videoHeight) {
    float viewWidth = getWidth();
    float viewHeight = getHeight();

    float scaleX = 1.0f;
    float scaleY = 1.0f;

    float viewRatio = viewWidth / viewHeight;
    float videoRatio = videoWidth / videoHeight;
    if (viewRatio > videoRatio) {
        // video is higher than view
        scaleY = videoHeight / videoWidth;
    } else {
        //video is wider than view
        scaleX = videoWidth / videoHeight;
    }

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);


    setTransform(matrix);
}
```

I had a rectangular views and it worked perfectly. But now views have 2 states: expanded (the old ones that are still rectangular) and collapsed (have smaller height.

So now video is stretched vertically in those collapsed views.

For instance I have view `1080x480` and video `360x640` but it looks like video is scaled and cropped to `1080x1080` and than stretched to `1080x480`.

What am I doing wrong here ?

UPD: Here are screenshots:
[image]

Comment: can you also add a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check `updateTextureViewSize` :

```
/**
 * Set the display options
 *
 * @param layout <ul>
 *               <li>{@link #VIDEO_LAYOUT_ORIGIN}
 *               <li>{@link #VIDEO_LAYOUT_SCALE}
 *               <li>{@link #VIDEO_LAYOUT_STRETCH}
 *               <li>{@link #VIDEO_LAYOUT_ZOOM}
 *               </ul>
 */
public void updateTextureViewSize(int layout,float videoWidth, float videoHeight) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
    DisplayMetrics disp = m_Context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int windowWidth = disp.widthPixels, windowHeight = disp.heightPixels;
    float windowRatio = windowWidth / (float) windowHeight;
    float videoRatio = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;
    m_iSurfaceHeight = videoHeight;
    m_iSurfaceWidth = videoWidth;
    if (VIDEO_LAYOUT_ORIGIN == layout && m_iSurfaceWidth < windowWidth && m_iSurfaceHeight < windowHeight) {
        lp.width = (int) (m_iSurfaceHeight * videoRatio);
        lp.height = m_iSurfaceHeight;
    } else if (layout == VIDEO_LAYOUT_ZOOM) {
        lp.width = windowRatio > videoRatio ? windowWidth : (int) (videoRatio * windowHeight);
        lp.height = windowRatio < videoRatio ? windowHeight : (int) (windowWidth / videoRatio);
    } else {
        boolean full = layout == VIDEO_LAYOUT_STRETCH;
        lp.width = (full || windowRatio < videoRatio) ? windowWidth : (int) (videoRatio * windowHeight);
        lp.height = (full || windowRatio > videoRatio) ? windowHeight : (int) (windowWidth / videoRatio);
        lp.leftMargin = (disp.widthPixels - lp.width) / 2;
        lp.topMargin = (disp.heightPixels - lp.height) / 2;
    }

    lp.leftMargin = (disp.widthPixels - lp.width) / 2;
    lp.topMargin = (disp.heightPixels - lp.height) / 2;

    getHolder().setFixedSize(m_iSurfaceWidth, m_iSurfaceHeight);

    setLayoutParams(lp);

    m_iVideoLayout = layout;
}
```

Comment: in this case, the textureview is inside a framelayout?

Comment: I think it should be in a `Frame Layout` or other containers layout. You can also see another example in this link: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/video-cropping-with-texture-view/21

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this issue next by multiplying or dividing scale factors by `viewRatio` (`width / height`):

```
    if (viewRatio > videoRatio) {
        // video is higher than view
        scaleY = videoHeight / videoWidth * viewRatio;
    } else {
        //video is wider than view
        scaleX = videoWidth / videoHeight / viewRatio;
    }
```

But I did not get why it works like this. According to my calculations if I have, for instance, view `1080x480` and video `360x640` video should be scaled to have width `x' = 1080` and height proportional. So height should be `y' = 640*1080/360` (`videoHeight * viewHeight / videoWidth`) and `x' = 1080`

According to this image:
[image]

`sx * 360 = 1080` => `sx = 1080 / 360`

`sy * 640 = 640*1080/360` => `sy = 1080 / 360`

Looks like it makes sense. If we need save proportions width and height should be multiplied by the same factor. But it does not work this way. Where is a mistake ? Is there any good doc on this ?

Comment: Yes, these formulas work well. The only thing that in my case was that one of parents of my class also had some manipulations on the matrix. So I had to take in count that manipulations.

Comment: i am doing the same on `ListView`. trying to achieve something similar to Instagram video.
Did you try this on a `ListView`? or in a normal activity?

Comment: I've been doing this in RecyclerView items

Comment: would you help me out sharing a sample code in stoping and playing the video when position changes on RecyclerView.